# Ajax stopped working after enabling csrf_protection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf-protection

I have changed the config file and set:

`$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`

After this the ajax calls have stopped working, when I set to `FALSE` ajax starts working.
I have to enable `csrf_protection` so how do I make my Ajax start working?

> Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: The link on that page, beheist - where it is explained in details is rebuilding so have no access to it, I tried it before hence found no option but to post it myself, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set csrf token like this:

```
$(function($) {
    // this bit needs to be loaded on every page where an ajax POST may happen
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
        }
    });

    // now you can use plain old POST requests like always
    $.post('site.com/controller/method', { name : 'Jerel' });
});
```

[Source](http://jerel.co/blog/2012/03/a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax)

Comment: Giving error at data: { csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')  } ??
May be I did not understand it very well. or is there something else that has to be done in config file.. ?

Comment: You need to install jquery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: All the scripts have stopped working.

Comment: yes thats because jquery can't access cookies, you need to use jquery cookie plugin to access cookies

Comment: Thank you. I guess that should do it.